# Classifiable data where the features change over time

Tags: data-request, classification

I am looking for large datasets to investigate classification on time-dependent data where the data's features change over time.

An example of this might be a large spam dataset that covers a clear change in trends over time of constructing spam that can by-pass spam classifiers.

In other words are their any publicly available datasets available where it is clear that a classifier might have to be re-trained after a period of time to cope with feature changes?

Comment: What formats can you handle?

Comment: The format doesn't really matter.